# Udible initial "click" when creating a sound file with sox

Tags: sox, beep, synthesizer

I'm trying to generate a few "beep" files with different tones that can be seemlessly looped.

At the moment I'm using a command like this:

`sox -n ./assets/notes/beep.mp3 -C 8 synth 5 trapezium 440 vol 0.7`

The file has a slightly audible "click" at the beginning, and that's disturbing when the player loop.

I've alreadi tried with no compression parameter (`-C 8`), and different volumes (`vol 0.7`.

What do I need to do to have a seemlessly looping file?

Comment: You could try a brief fade-in, e.g. `fade t 0.01`. On my system I heard a click at the end rather than at the start, so YMMW, but fading seems to help (on both sides: `fade t 0.01 5 0.01`).

Comment: Tried, but doesn't worked for me. Thank you for the suggestion!